# ejecutar otro funcion si no llaman a un objeto con javascript

Tags: poo, funciones, variables

¿como hago que la clausura me llame una alert si el usuario no llama a confirm?

```
var cla=(function(){
function a(){
alert("no llamo a confirm");
}
return{
confirm:function(text){
var p=confirm(text);
}
}
});
cla();
```

¿como hago que llame `a()` la funcion a si no llama a `confirm()`?

Answer (score 1):

Confirm devolverá `true` si se da al "Ok" y `false` en cualquier otro caso.

Como ya estás guardando la respuesta en `p` solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente

```
if (!p) {
   a()
}
```